# CakePHP - Utility method for checking a string is a valid email address?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-1.3, email-validation

In a controller, I need to check a string to see if it is a valid email address.  Is there an existing method in Cake that I can use to check this?

It has nothing to do with models, so I don't want to use a validate array.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I found the core Validation class. Validation::email()

```
App::uses('Validation', 'Utility');

class MyController extends AppController
{
    public function myAction()
    {
        $isValid = Validation::email('person@example.com'); // Returns true or false
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to use it with maybe a few lines of code?

Comment: @mgPePe Updated with example

Answer (score 0):

you may still use the model validation for it

```
$this->Model->set($data);
if ($this->Model->validates()) {}
```

your current model should have a rule for "email" if you are handling emails in this controller. or you can create one here.